# How to detect Xamarin.iOS on demand resource path after being downloaded?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In my Xamarin.iOS project, I added an on demand resource tag and implemented code to download resources using `beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler` called on the `NSBundleResourceRequest` instance.

This API downloaded the resources and after that called the completion block when the resource was available, but when I tried to get the image in the UI using `UIImage.FromBundle` and `NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource` it always returns `null`.

How to get a path of downloaded "on demand" resources in Xamarin.iOS?

Add code for reference -

```
request = new NSBundleResourceRequest(new[] { "OnLoad" });
        request.BeginAccessingResources((NSError obj) =>
        {
            if (obj != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Error occurred: {0}");
            else
            {
                NSOperationQueue.MainQueue.AddOperation(() =>
                {
                    InvokeOnMainThread(() => 
                    {
                        var imagePath1 = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("image1", "jpg");
                        var image = UIImage.FromFile(imagePath1);
                    });

                });
            }
        });
```

If I add images to assets.xcassets folder (1x,2x,3x) then I can't get downloaded image. But if I add images directly to resources folder (only one image-no 1x or 2x or 3x) then after downloading NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource returns correct path

Comment: Have you tried in one of the folders listed in Environment.SpecialFolder?Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

Comment: Thanks Daniele. Tried with this but didn't works for me. If I add images to assets.xcassets  folder then I can't get downloaded image. But if I add images directly to resources folder then after downloading NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource returns correct path

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I assume you  set `On-Demand Resources` properly and downloaded successfully.

You can try

```
NSBundleResourceRequest request = xxxx;
request.BeginAccessingResources((NSError error)=> {
   if (error == null)
   {
      NSError err = null;
      string str = request.Bundle.BundlePath;
      NSFileManager fm = NSFileManager.DefaultManager;   
      string[] dirArray = fm.GetDirectoryContent(str, out err);
      var result = dirArray.Where(x => x.Contains(".png"));
   }
   else {
       request.EndAccessingResources();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Cole. Assume in above code if (error == null) then I need to use NSFileManager options. But app crash at imageArray. reason Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI evaluateWithObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: @ Cole - I am using Xamarin.iOS. Please check above code. I tried your code but error always null and so I tried without error checking. But result doesn't contains downloaded image path or file name.

Comment: @Vishnu what is the value of dirArray

Comment: It contains {string[25]} - values with dll, .exe, assets files etc

Comment: These are dirArray contents - AssetPackManifestTemplate.plistAssets.carInfo.plistLaunchScreen.storyboardcMain.storyboardcMono.Security.dllMono.Security.pdbMonoTouchDebugConfiguration.txtmscorlib.dllmscorlib.pdbONDemad_nativeONDemad_native.exeONDemad_native.pdbOnDemandResources.plistPkgInforuntime-options.plistSettings.bundleSystem.Core.dllSystem.Core.pdbSystem.dllSystem.pdbSystem.Xml.dllSystem.Xml.pdbXamarin.iOS.dllXamarin.iOS.dll.mdb

Comment: @Vishnu Can you try to find those image files with the bundlepath ？